# How to change activity title when switching between tabs in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There are many answers to that question in Java language, but I can not apply it 
using Kotlin.

I use ViewPager to switch between tabs and I want MainActivity title to be changed every time when I swipe.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        container.adapter = TabPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)    
        container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))
    }

    override fun setTitle(title: CharSequence?) {
        supportActionBar?.title = title
    }
}
```

I use "kotlin-android-extensions", so container is id of ViewPager and tabs is id of TabLayout. I also created class TabPagerAdapter that extends FragmentPagerAdapter. It returns correct tab, which is Fragment derivative, with getItem method. I tried to achieve my goal by overriding getPageTitle method but it doesn't work.

```
class TabPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : 
FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment {
        return when (p0) {
            else -> TestTab.newInstance()
            }
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return "test title"
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

My tab example:

```
class NotificationsTab : Fragment() {
    private val _title = "Notifications"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): NotificationsTab {
            return NotificationsTab()
        }
    }
}
```

I want variable `_title` to be the `MainActivity` title.
XMLs that I use:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.androidtest.activities.MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="63"
            app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_notifications"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_weight="390"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_notifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="notifications"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="56sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand when users swipe between tabs, you will set the tab's text as title of the activity. Here is a solution

First remove all TabItem tags from `activity_main.xml` layout file because you are using TabLayout with ViewPager. The ViewPager will handle how to setup tab (number of tabs, fragment at each tab, title at each tab, etc).

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp">

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.TabItem-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/tab_profile"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="1"/>-->

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.TabItem-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/tab_notifications"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="2"/>-->

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Then change your code in `MainActivity`

```
container.adapter = TabPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
// Comment-out or remove these lines
// container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
// tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))

// Pass viewpager to tablayout to setup tabs.
tabs.setupWithViewPager(container)

// Handle event when users swipe to a tab, here we set tab's text as title of the activity.
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
        title = tab.text // the value of tab's text is the returned value from `getPageTitle` method in TabPagerAdapter class.
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }
})

// For the first time open the app, we set first tab's title as title of this activity
title = container.adapter!!.getPageTitle(0)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanation wasn't clear, I tried to do my best. I have added example of my tab class. I hope my problem will be understandable now.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I did everything as you advised. What can be the reason for that? Don't you think that there should be `return` before `when` in getPageTitle?

Comment: Yeah I miss the `return` keyword. Because your code is not fully so I can't reproduce the issue. I just give you steps how to do that.

Comment: I copied everything except xmls. I noticed that getPageTitle method in TabPagerAdapter doesn't work for me at all. Omitting fragments, even if I make this method always returns one string, it doesn't change title of MainActivity.

Comment: Ok can you please your xml layout files. I will reproduce and figure out root cause.

Comment: I put xmls, there are two tabs, but their Kotlin class looks the same, I didn't copied it because it would be code doubling.

Comment: in styles.xml I added  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182947/discussion-between-son-truong-and-prenc).

Answer (score 0):

```
viewPagerAtmosphericInfo.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

}

override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

}

override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
   // code here
})
```

Comment: `viewPagerAtmosphericInfo` what is this

Comment: @TimCastelijns This is Viewpager

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the title of your activity with tabs, You have to set the  title of activity(s) actionbar which you can set from fragment by using activity instance.

Example :

```
//initialize activity instance
lateinit var mActivity: AppCompatActivity

//get activity inside your onViewCreated of fragment
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    mActivity = activity as MainActivity

}

// inside your fragment
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        //change your title from here, make sure that activity is not null
        mActivity.supportActionBar?.title = "Your Title"
    }
}
```

Let me now if you have any query! :)

Comment: Your solution does not work for me, when I switch between tabs, the activity title changes inconsistently. Sometimes there appears a title that belongs to the next tab.

Comment: You have to set title on visibility of fragments

Comment: What do you mean by this? Can you explain?

Comment: In fragments, you can get visibility of fragments so in that check if fragment is visible then only set the title

Comment: I created `if` statement in onViewCreated method that checks if fragment is visible and now it shows consistently title of the next tab.

Comment: Now app crashes with `lateinit property mActivity has not been initialized` error

Comment: saying that instance not initialized please initialize that

Comment: this time `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.androidtest.activities.MainActivity`

Comment: Man it's basic error that you have solve by yourself